# lex program for print function

Tags: compiler-construction, yacc, lex, lexical-analysis

I am very new to lex and yacc. please help me to write the lex code for
my below requirement.

input:

```
print "myprint":arg
```

expected output:

```
print - is print function
myprint - is a print string
arg - is a print argument
```

myexaple code:

```
arg = 10
print "myprint":arg //myprint10
```

I know Stack Overflow users will not give the answer for exercise kind of
question. It is difficult for me to write using lex as i am new user

Comment: There a quite a few books on learning to use lex&yacc (or flex&bison) -- one of them is probably a recommended text for your class.  There are even some you can find for free download.  You should read (and understand) one and try some things before asking questions here...

Answer (score 1):

@sujin without just giving you the answer, you might consider seeking out examples of lex and yacc files.  There are two here that might head you in the right direction:

lex http://www.quut.com/c/ANSI-C-grammar-l-2011.html

yacc http://www.quut.com/c/ANSI-C-grammar-y-2011.html

The lex file should give you an idea of the constants and patterns that you'll want to create to represent your tokens.  The yacc will give you an idea of how a grammar is structured.

Additionally, O'Reilly produced an excellent book entitled "Lex & Yacc" (although a bit dated now) which has some simplified examples.  It is relatively easy to follow and worthwhile if you can locate a copy (print or digital).

Comment: I gone through the link. If you can pls give the code to my requirement